# Android SDK Error with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with my eclipse on every computer for 2 days. I have installed the Android SDK from the official web site and I had been programming a long time without errors. But now Eclipse says I need to update the Eclipse version to set the Build Path.
On every start of Eclipse, it asks me for updates. When I click "yes", nothing happens and Eclipse shows this error:
[image]

This error comes up when I fix the build path error on Eclipse:
[image]

Please help me :(

greetings coco07!

Comment: In Eclipse go to Window -> SDK Manager and check for updates there. Using Help -> Check For Updates won't work if that's what you've been doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try updating your ADT from here:

*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!

I also found something useful for you:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F

Hope this helps.